# uninitialized constant DashboardController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need an admin panel for my application so I have decided to install active admin.

I followed the steps on the official website.

But I get stuck when I try to migrate the database.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "username" of relation "users" already exists
```

When I try run the server, my application doesn not open anymore too.

Please suggest me something, is there a way to uninstall and re-install it.
Or an easy fix?

Comment: Can you paste the migration that is causing the error?

Comment: what did you use as reference? [this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/0-installation.md) page? maybe you used User as resource instead of an Admin? If you use this command: rails g active_admin:install User and you already have a migration that creates a table Users you get an error. If you want a dedicate "administrator" type of user simply use this: rails g active_admin:install Admin